# Pay HELOC or NOT

Tags: taxes

I am 65 years old retired and collecting SS.  I sold my personal residence, and move back to my old rental house which I have a HELOC of $100K which I pay about $375 monthly interest only.  As of now, I have the option to pay my HELOC or re-invest the money from the proceed of my personal residence.  My question is,  should I not pay my HELOC and continue investing on real estate to further my investment or stop and pay my HELOC and be debt free.

Thanks for your advice

AL

Comment: This is totally opinion based, but I would pay the thing off.

Comment: (I agree, precisely, with exactly what PeteB said!  :) )

Answer (score 6):

Real Estate is all local. With no details on how you’d invest the home proceeds, it’s not a simple answer.

If you are able to invest the $100k and get a return significantly higher than the 4.5% you are paying, who would argue with that?

Since you already owned a rental, I don’t need to offer the warnings I’d feel compelled to give to the new landlord.

Keep in mind, the heloc interest is no longer deductible.

Comment: Nicely put.  Real estate is all local.